# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am getting error as:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context swift4"

I am making local notification reminder page for iPhone app.
I am using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate 
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if(UIApplication.instancesRespond(to: Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil))
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: And why do you have so much Swift 2 code when you claim to be using Swift 4? Perhaps you should not copy and paste from out-of-date tutorials.

Comment: UIApplication.sharedApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil)

Comment: That's written in Swift 2. Please find a tutorial written in at least Swift 3 to get the correct syntax of that line and others in your question.

Comment: @juee Please update the question with the above clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because the syntax of code is not correct. The code you posted here is in `Swift-2` which is why it is giving you syntax error.

Use the below code in `Swift-4`:

```
UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings.init(types: [.alert, .badge], categories: nil))
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: That isn't the only line of Swift 2 code that needs to be fixed. The `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` signature is incorrect as well. And the selector syntax should be updated to use `#selector`.

Comment: I know. I only gave the solution for the code where he was getting the error.